# Permission Denied 401 when sending axios request between localhosts (React and Django)

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, http-status-code-401

I set up a Django backend and a React frontend. The Django app renders the index.html where the production ready JS created with react is found.

But when developing locally, I develop the react frontend on my `localserver:3000`. Now I am trying to fetch data from my Django  backend, but I keep on getting a 401 Permission error. I know the problem is because the request comes from different hosts, but I don't know how to solve it.

My backend API's use token authentication, but even if I send the bearer token in the headers, I still get the same error:

[image: chrome dev tools response]

My code for the request is simple:

```
axios
    .get(`http://localhost:8000/path/to/data/`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${'here is my token'}`,
        },
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

When my react app makes this a production ready bundle and executes this on localhost:8000 there is no permission error, but I need to make it work from localhost:3000 because this is where I develop my app.

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance

EDIT:

My CORS:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at this article https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/django-cors-guide/

Comment: Thanks you for the hint. Unfortunately I have my CORS configured - to my knowledge correctly. I update my question with my CORS config

Comment: Maybe try setting only those: 
`CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True`
`CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True`

`CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://127.0.0.1", "http://localhost:3000"]`

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I still get a 401

Comment: Hmmm, can you share your `settings.py` and are you calling an `APIView` with the `ajax` request?

Comment: I updated my question. And yes, I am calling an API view, to be precise a django-rest API view which is only accessible by staff users. Thus, I am trying to authenticate via a token, generated for a staff user

Comment: Ahhh I found the error. I am authenticating with JWT and not with Bearer.... @ 
antpngl92 thank you man, you made me look into the right things. Really appreciated

Comment: No problem at all. I am glad you have solved the issue! Don't forget to update the post with the issue and solution. It might be useful to other ppl in future.

Answer (score 0):

Since my rest-configuration is implemented with JWT-Token, I needed to send requests with `Authorization: JWT ${'here is my token'}`, instead of `Authorization: Bearer ${'here is my token'}`. Just three letters, but it solved the problem :). Thanks to antpngl92 for troubleshooting with me.